# Beautiful soup with find all only gives the last result

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve all the products from a page using beautiful soup. The page has pagination, and to solve it I have made a loop to make the retrieve work for all pages.
But, when I move to the next step and try to "find_all()" the tags, it only gives the data from the last page.
If I try when one isolated page it works fine, so I guest that it is a problem with getting all the html from all pages.

My code is the next:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3 as ur

http = ur.PoolManager()

base_url = 'https://www.kiwoko.com/tienda-de-perros-online.html'

for x in range (1,int(33)+1):
    dog_products_http = http.request('GET', base_url+'?p='+str(x))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dog_products_http.data, 'html.parser')
    print (soup.prettify)
```

and ones it has finished:

```
soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'item product product-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'})
```

As I said, if I do not use the for range and only retrieve one page (example: https://www.kiwoko.com/tienda-de-perros-online.html?p=10, it works fine and gives me the 36 products.

I have copied the "soup" in a word file and search the class to see if there is a problem, but there are all the 1.153 products I'm looking for.

So, I think the soup is right, but as I look for "more than one html" I do not think that the find all is working good.

¿What could be the problem?

Comment: In your loop you are overwriting the same `soup` variable over and over. In the end you only call `find_all` on the final one. Put the find inside the loop.

Comment: you're right. Problem solve. I have entered all the code lines I had after that into the loop and now it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want your `find` inside the loop but here is a way to copy the ajax call the page makes which allows you to return more items per request and also to calculate the  number of pages dynamically and make requests for all products.

I re-use connection with Session for efficiency.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, math

results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.kiwoko.com/tienda-de-perros-online.html?p=1&product_list_limit=54&isAjax=1&_=1560702601779').json()
    soup = bs(r['categoryProducts'], 'lxml')
    results.append(soup.select('.product-item-details'))
    product_count = int(soup.select_one('.toolbar-number').text)  
    pages = math.ceil(product_count / 54)

    if pages > 1:
        for page in range(2, pages + 1):
            r = s.get('https://www.kiwoko.com/tienda-de-perros-online.html?p={}&product_list_limit=54&isAjax=1&_=1560702601779'.format(page)).json()
            soup = bs(r['categoryProducts'], 'lxml')
            results.append(soup.select('.product-item-details'))

results = [result for item in results for result in item]
print(len(results))
# parse out from results what you want, as this is a list of tags, or do in loop above
```